# what is GCC compiler option to get Segment Override prefix in x86

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, linker, x86

I have memory layout (In Increasing memory addr) like :

Code Section (0-4k), Data Section(4k-8k), Stack Section(8k-12k), CustomData Section(12k-16k).

I have put some special arrays, structs in Custom Data Section.

As i know, Data Segment (#DS)Selector will be used for any Data related compiler code.

So Data Section(4k-8k) will have #DS by default for all operation. Except some str op where ES may be used. Like:

```
mov    $0xc00,%eax
addl   $0xd, (%eax)
```

But, I want to use Extra Segment(#ES) selector for CustomData access. I would define a new GDT entry for ES with different Base and Limit.  like:

```
mov    $0x3400,%eax
addl   $0xd, %es:(%eax)
```

So my question is:

Does GCC has any x86 compiler flag, which can be used to tell compiler that use #ES for CustomData Section code access.?

Means, compiler flag which will generate code using #ES for CustomData Section.?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You are trying to revive the horrors of 16-bit x86 coding.  You'll have to change the operating system and compiler first.  Odds that your patches will be accepted are zero so it is a build-a-submarine-in-the-basement kind of project.

Comment: Is is possible by any other method?

Answer (score 0):

While the question is asking for an option to make gcc's code-gen use an es prefix for accessing a custom section, IF you wanted to do it in hand-written code, the AT&T syntax already allows e.g. %es:(%eax).

Note, this may break rep-string instructions which gcc sometimes inlines; fs or gs would be the only sane choices, and are still usable even in x86-64.

(Making this comment community wiki based on useful critique by Peter Cordes.)

Comment: The question is asking for an option to make gcc's code-gen use an `es` prefixes for accessing a custom section, not how to do it in hand-written code.  (Weird, because that would break rep-string instructions which gcc sometimes inlines;  `fs` or `gs` would be the only sane choices, and are still usable even in x86-64)  Anyway, if you're writing asm by hand, AT&T syntax already allows `%es:(%eax)` so there's no need to mention the numeric prefix values.

Comment: @PeterCordes.  True on both points.  Making answer community wiki and replacing with yours.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the example from the [clang language-extension docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#target-specific-extensions)

> ```
> #define GS_RELATIVE __attribute__((address_space(256)))
> int foo(int GS_RELATIVE *P) {
>   return *P;
> }
> ```
>
> Which compiles to (on X86-32):
>
> ```
> _foo:
>         movl    4(%esp), %eax         # load the arg
>         movl    %gs:(%eax), %eax      # use it with its prefix
>         ret
> ```

address-space 256 is `gs`, 257 is `fs`, and 258 is `ss`.

The docs don't mention `es`; compilers normally assume that `es`=`ds` so they can freely inline `rep movs` or `rep stos` for memcpy / memset if they choose to do so based on tuning options.  Library implementations of `memcpy` or `memset` may also use rep stos/movs on some CPUs.  Related: [Why is std::fill(0) slower than std::fill(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558907/why-is-stdfill0-slower-than-stdfill1)

Obviously this is really low-level stuff, and only makes sense if you've already set the GS or FS base address.  (`wrfsbase`).  Beware that i386 Linux uses `gs` for thread-local storage in user-space, while x86-64 Linux uses `fs`.

---

I'm not aware of extensions like this for gcc, ICC, or MSVC.

Well, there is `__thread` in GNU C, which will use `%gs:` or `%fs:` prefixes as appropriate for the target platform.  [How does the gcc `__thread` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32245103/how-does-the-gcc-thread-work).