# How is GCC's __thread implemented?

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, pthreads, thread-local-storage

How is `__thread` in gcc implemented? Is it simply a wrapper over `pthread_getspecific` and `pthread_setspecific`?

With my program that uses the posix API for TLS, I'm kind of disappointed now seeing that 30% of my program runtime is spent on `pthread_getspecific`. I called it on the entry of each function call that needs the resource. The compiler doesn't seem to optimize out `pthread_getspecific` after inlining optimization. So after the functions are inlined the code is basically searching for the correct TLS pointer again and again to get the same pointer returned.

Will `__thread` help me in this situation? I know that there is `thread_local` in C11, but the gcc I have doesn't support it yet. (But now I see that my gcc does support `_Thread_local` just not the macro.)

I know I can simply test it and see. But I have to go somewhere else now, and I'd like to know better on a feature before I attempt a quite big rewrite.

Comment: `__thread` is implemented differently on different platforms, on some (you didn't tell us which one you are programming for), it might be implemented with `pthread_getspecific`.

Comment: Please give us more information! I'd really like to solve your problem but right now I don't know enough about what platform you use / how you compile your code to be able to give you an answer as to how to make thread local storage perform better.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), e.g. [GCC 5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) do support C11 and its `thread_local` (if compiling with e.g. `gcc -std=c11`). As [FUZxxl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417501/fuzxxl) commented, you could use (instead of C11 `thread_local`) the `__thread` qualifier supported by older GCC versions. Read about [Thread Local Storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage).

`pthread_getspecific` is indeed quite slow (it is in the POSIX library, so is not provided by GCC but e.g. by [GNU glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)) since it involves a function call. Using `thread_local` variables will very probably be faster.

Look into the source code of [MUSL's `thread/pthread_getspecific.c` file](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/thread/pthread_getspecific.c)
for an example of implementation. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2459752/841108) to a related question.

And `_thread` & `thread_local` are (often) not magically translated to calls to `pthread_getspecific`. They usually involve some specific address mode and/or register (details are implementation specific, related to the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface); on Linux, I guess that since x86-64 has more registers & address modes, its implementation of TLS is faster than on i386), with help from the [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler), the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) and the [runtime system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_system). It could happen on the contrary that some implementations of `pthread_getspecific` are using some internal `thread_local` variables (in your implementation of POSIX threads).

As an example, compiling the following code

```
#include <pthread.h>

const extern pthread_key_t key;

__thread int data;

int
get_data (void) {
  return data;
}

int
get_by_key (void) {
  return *(int*) (pthread_getspecific (key));
}
```

using GCC 5.2 (on Debian/Sid) with `gcc -m32 -S -O2 -fverbose-asm` gives the following code for `get_data` using TLS:

```
  .type get_data, @function
get_data:
.LFB3:
  .cfi_startproc
  movl  %gs:data@ntpoff, %eax   # data,
  ret
.cfi_endproc
```

and the following code of `get_by_key` with an *explicit call* to `pthread_getspecific`:

```
get_by_key:
 .LFB4:
  .cfi_startproc
  subl  $24, %esp   #,
  .cfi_def_cfa_offset 28
  pushl key # key
  .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
  call  pthread_getspecific #
  movl  (%eax), %eax    # MEM[(int *)_4], MEM[(int *)_4]
  addl  $28, %esp   #,
  .cfi_def_cfa_offset 4
  ret
  .cfi_endproc
```

Hence using TLS with `__thread` (or `thread_local` in C11) should probably be faster than using `pthread_getspecific` (avoiding the overhead of a call).

Notice that `thread_local` is a [convenience macro defined in `<threads.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thread_local) (a C11 standard header).

Comment: Does pthread_setspecific do more extra work than the built-in TLS?

Comment: `__thread` is a pre-C11 extension of gcc that has the same semantic as C11's `_Thread_local`, in fact it guarantees a bit more than `_Thread_local`. `pthread_getspecific` does not necessarily involve a function call, it can be implemented as a macro.

Comment: @FUZxxl: it could be implemented by a macro (but I guess that the standard requires that you might use it thru a function pointer), but it usually is not implemented as a macro

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Standard says it's allowed to be macro, and it's weird that the glibc doesn't implement it as such.

Comment: @xiver77 It is not specified how `__thread` and `_Thread_local` (i.e. built-in TLS) are implemented. An implementation could very well use `pthread_getspecific` and `pthread_setspecific` to implement it, although thats not the case on usual UNIX-like operating systems.

Comment: TLS is implemented both on i386 and amd64 Linux with a segment register (`%fs` for i386, `%gs` for amd64). The speed difference is negligible.

Answer (score 4):

gcc's `__thread` has exactly the same semantic as C11's `_Thread_local`. You don't tell us what platform you are programming for as the implementation details vary between platforms. For example, on x86 Linux, gcc should compile access to thread local variables as memory instructions with a `%fs` segment prefix instead of invoking `pthread_getspecific`.

Comment: I'm using an intel cpu. So you mean gcc uses a special register like the stack pointer register but dedicated to the TLS? Does pthread_getspecific do the same thing?

Comment: @xiver77 “i'm using an intel cpu” is not enough information. What operating system and architecture are you programming for? Intel makes CPUs with many different architectures. On i386 platforms were the ABI supports this, the `%fp` segment register is set to a non-zero base address that points to the thread's thread-local data. I can't tell you if gcc can do this on your platform as you don't give me enough information. Could you also give me the version of gcc, the invocation of gcc and assembly output (use the `-S` switch)?

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. My platform is Ubuntu 15.10 i386 gcc 4.9.2. I'll also check and see the assembly output for `__thread` right now.

Comment: @xiver77 How do you invoke gcc? On i386 Linux, gcc should compile access to `__thread` variables without invoking `pthread_getspecific`. Either another part of your code invokes `pthread_getspecific` or something weird happens.

Comment: @xiver77 This assembly does not invoke `pthread_getspecific` at all. I guess the calls come from somewhere else.

Comment: Also, it's funny that the compiler generates `%gs` relative accesses whereas it should generate `%fs` relative accesses. How do you invoke gcc?

Comment: I think it's because I've installed a 32bit Linux. BTW you may have misunderstood my question a little. I did explicitly call `pthread_getspecific` in my original program. That's why my second paragraph is there. I'll edit my question to prevent confusion.

Comment: @xiver77 Ah, I see. Sorry for that. In this case, I can gladly say: yes, `__thread` will give you a decent performance increase.